# Counting & Filtering Items Based on Range

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

I have a list of cars, and I need to let users filter them based on mileage ranges. (These are fixed ranges, like 0 - 9,999, 10,000 – 19,999, etc.)

I've hard-coded the filter ranges. I'd like to show the count of each range with the label, e.g. *0 – 9,999 (5)*, hide the filters that don't have any items, and then filter the items out when a user clicks on an option.

Here's what the filters look like currently:

```
<label class="filter-input">
    <input type="checkbox" name="0-9999" class="mileage-input" value="0-9999" /> 0&ndash;9,999
</label>
<label class="filter-input">
    <input type="checkbox" name="10000-19999" class="mileage-input" value="10000-19999" /> 10,000&ndash;19,999
</label>
<label class="filter-input">
    <input type="checkbox" name="20000-29999" class="mileage-input" value="20000-29999" /> 20,000&ndash;29,999
</label>
<label class="filter-input">
    <input type="checkbox" name="30000-39999" class="mileage-input" value="30000-39999" /> 30,000&ndash;39,999
</label>
Etc.
```

and here's an example of one of the items:

```
<div class="car-div">
    <p class="car-info" data-year="1999" data-make="Ferrari" data-model="Versa" data-mileage="24,420" data-price="$230,091">
        <span>1999 Ferrari Versa</span>
        <br>$230,091
    </p>
</div>
```

I'm a little stuck, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need to clarify a bit your question. You're probably getting these data from backend along with the filters and show them in frontend. Are you echoing the above filter from backend? If this is the case, you could add an extra class for those that do not have any items and hide them. But still, we will need some more info.

Comment: I am getting the data and filters from the backend, but I do have full control over how they are displayed on the front end, so I can add any extra classes to the items.

Comment: In this case, you can check for each filter range if there are any items, and if they don't, hide the filter.

Comment: i recommend you make 2 separate attributes for this ... minvalue="0" maxvalue = "9999"...will make it all easier

Comment: Thank you. I will try the 2 separate attributes. So you would hide all the filters, and loop through the cars and make the filters appear when there's a match? I'm also not 100% sure how to show the counts next to each filter.